# JQuery trigger anchor's onclick event without sending browser to href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have an `a` tag with an `href` and an `onclick` function, but when the user clicks the link I don't want the browser to go to the `href` but just execute the `onclick`. I tried the following:

```js
function testFunc() {
  document.getElementById("testDiv").innerHTML = "it works!";
}

$('.testClass').click(function(event) {
  $(this).trigger("onclick");
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://www.google.com" class="testClass" onclick="testFunc()">click me</a> 

<div id="testDiv"></div>
```

- Note: while it appears to work in the snippet editor, in a full page the browser does go to Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is taht you trigger click two times , first when clicking the element then when clicking happened so you should put other function inside the fist one after preventing default .
Use `event.preventDefault();`

I replaced this line `<a href="http://www.google.com" class="testClass" onclick="testFunc()">click me</a>` with this `<a href="http://www.google.com" class="testClass" >click me</a>` then modified script

```js
function testFunc() {
  document.getElementById("testDiv").innerHTML = "it works!";
}
$('.testClass').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  testFunc();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://www.google.com" class="testClass">click me</a>

<div id="testDiv"></div>
```

Put it like this :

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script> 


 </head>
 <body>

<a href="http://www.google.com" class="testClass">click me</a> 

<div id="testDiv"></div>
<script>
  function testFunc() {
    document.getElementById("testDiv").innerHTML = "it works!";
  }

  $('.testClass').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    testFunc();

  });
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No it is not like what he did , see the difrent he prevent the defaul then trigger click again

Comment: It still goes to Google after clicking. (not in the snippet editor, but in a full page)

Comment: copy my code dont use your code , i have some changes

Comment: @j08691 i think you didn't read my code well , copy it and test it

Comment: as i said remove this line <a href="http://www.google.com" class="testClass" onclick="testFunc()">click me</a>

Comment: i saw your code you still not removed on click from anchor

Comment: @DanielWilliams copy my code as it is and test it , copy all code what i wrotte

Comment: Here is your code: http://monstatour.com/index2.html and it still goes to Google.

Comment: put the secript before closing body tag not in head tag ,

Comment: @DanielWilliams your problem with my code is that you put the script in head tag not in body tag , test my code again

Comment: Ok thanks, the problem all along was my Javascript should have been in the bottom of the page. I just took out the line `$(this).trigger("onclick");` from my original code and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: @j08691 you should vote not down vote my answer , still my answer is different than the original one

Comment: @MohammedElhag You shouldn't tell others how to vote and your analysis is wrong, however this is only evinced by the example the OP gave when they showed their website. They're running their jQuery code before the DOM is ready, so it has no effect. So what happens when the link is clicked is that all of the jQuery is ignored and only `testFunc()` runs. That changes the innerHTML of the div, and then the link is followed. There's nothing inherently wrong with the OP's code that they posted in their question, and they used, `preventDefault()` properly.

Comment: @j08691 I just want to show you that you were wrong and not order you , and still the OP problem is not only to put the code inside head tag but the code itself , and even he said that the origanl it works , it still not work for me unless changing to my code , because he made preventing default then trigger click again so it make preventing again and again and nothing will happen

Comment: @MohammedElhag I guess you still have a lot to learn but no, I was not wrong. Plus, your explanation makes little to no sense. Try re-reading what I wrote.

Comment: Ok , when i write use prevent default i know he use it but i supersized when people made vote up with return false , so i just wanted to say keep prevent default as it is , and you are right I have a lot to learn and i wish to learn more , thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

You don´t need all that, just adding return false to your onclick handler would work:

```js
function testFunc() {
  document.getElementById("testDiv").innerHTML = "it works!";
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://www.google.com" class="testClass" onclick="testFunc()">click me</a> 

<div id="testDiv"></div>
```

Comment: It still goes to Google after clicking. (not in the snippet editor, but in a full page)

Comment: @DanielWilliams You'll need to post a [mcve] in your question so that we can reproduce the issue. As it stand now, your code seems fine. Also, have you checked your browser's console for errors?

Comment: if it still goes to google, your function is not being executed. Add a console.log() to it

Comment: @DanielWilliams in your latest example your jQuery code either needs to go inside a document.read() call or at the end of the page. You're running it before the actual elements have been rendered to the page. See https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/